# Can you take alcohol to Sri Lanka from Australia?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, duty-free, sri-lanka

Can you take duty-free alcohol to Sri Lanka from Australia?

Answer (score 4):

According to [Duty Free Allowances](http://www.airport.lk/mria/traveler_info/duty_free_allowances.php) from the Mattala Rajapaksa International Airport (MRIA) site, yes you can.  The duty free limits are:

> **Passengers over the age of 18 years of age are allowed the following
>   free imports:**
>
> Two bottles of wine as well as one and half a litre of
>   spirits.

Comment: This answer is the correct answer. Moreover, it is illegal to import cigarettes too. https://www.worldtravelguide.net/guides/asia/sri-lanka/money-duty-free/

Answer (score 0):

**Exporting duty free alcohol from India**

As Peter M states, going outbound from Mattala Rajapaksa International Airport (MRIA) The limits are:

> Passengers over the age of 18 years of age are allowed the following free imports:
>
> Two bottles of wine as well as one and half a litre of spirits.

---

**Importing duty free alcohol into Australia**

Australia is known to have a tough stance at border control, espeically customs. [Australia's home affairs](https://www.homeaffairs.gov.au/trav/ente/duty-free-concessions) indicate that you can only bring 2.25 litres of alcohol as duty free.

> **Alcoholic beverages**
>
> If you are aged 18 years or over, you can bring 2.25 litres of alcoholic beverages duty free into Australia with you.

It further states:

> There are no duty free concessions on tobacco or alcohol for travellers aged under 18 years of age.

---

**Disclaimer:**

It is often forgotten that importing goods into a country may result a duty to imposed on it. The permissible amount of duty free to be exported from one country may be more than the country that the passenger is importing it into. Australia has strict customs, therefore it is recommended that you bring no more than 2.25 litres of alcohol into Australia, or you will be paying duty on it.

Answer (score 0):

This link gives you the allowances at Colombo International Airport.
https://srilanka.shopdutyfree.com/en/custom-allowances